# Checking if 3G is connected always returns false (even when the device is connected)

Tags: android, 3g

Whether or not the device has 3g/data activated. Any idea of what's happening?
Thank you

My code:

```
public boolean isConnected3G(){
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo[] networks = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
    for (NetworkInfo ni : networks) 
        if ("MOBILE".equalsIgnoreCase(ni.getTypeName())){
            Log.d(TAG,""+ni.isConnected());
            if (ni.isConnected())
                return true;
        }
    return false;       
}
```

Comment: Did you try this code? What does it return?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() instead of cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
and check the network information

Comment: Thanks but I can't target MOBILE with cm.getActiveNetworkInfo()

Comment: when you execute cm.getActiveNetworkInfo(), what is the type of network you are receiving?
And instead of getting the name of type of the network, why don't you just get a type via ni.getType() and compare it with constants from ConnectivityManager (i.e. TYPE_MOBILE, TYPE_MOBILE_HIPRI etc.)?